# Can I play movie files on my PC?

Tags: windows-7, video, playback

My PC has the following specifications:

```
Celeron CPU G550 Sandy Bridge 1155 2.6 Ghz
2x2 GB DDR3 1333 Mhz RAM
VGA built in CPU "Intel HD Graphics"
Standard 500 GB HDD 3.5"
Windows 7 64bit
```

Can I play movie files on this PC to the TV with it not blocking on me?

Answer (score 1):

Intel HD graphics are surprisingly good.

Don't expect to be doing 1080p video whilst doing power hungry stuff in the background, but, with a good program such as VLC and everything else shut, you should be able to play standard 1080p videos fine (not including actual blu-ray decoding...).

Answer (score 1):

'Yes'. Though in my experience, you'd (naturally) need appropriate codecs, and in some cases tweak things a little. While you don't have the advantage of quick sync (which is awesome), you still have some hardware accelerated video decoding, and its a fairly fast processor. Considering anandtech [tried gaming](http://www.anandtech.com/show/4524/the-sandy-bridge-pentium-review-pentium-g850-g840-g620-g620t-tested) on the adaptor, and most modern graphics cards are designed for playing 1080p, it *ought* to have no issues playing movie files.

If you experience bottlenecks - its probably somewhere else.